After executing the Main method that writes a XML-File, the Main method that should read the file is not executed
I have two classes which contain Main methods, one is called WriteXML, this is the class that writes the data from the User-Class (this class does not contain a Main method) into a XML-File.
The second class with a Main method is called ReadXML, which is supposed to read the XML-File that was written directly before by the WriteXML class.
The WriteXML class:
using System;
using System.Xml;
using static User;

internal class WriteXML
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        User user1 = new User();
        user1.Vorname = "Max";
        user1.Nachname = "Mustermann";
        user1.Geburtstag = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1);
        user1.Alter(user1.Geburtstag);

        XmlTextWriter textWriter = new XmlTextWriter("C:\\Users\\ematric\\Desktop\\Philipp\\Solution/myXmlFile.xml", null);
        textWriter.WriteStartDocument();

        textWriter.WriteComment("First Comment XmlTextWriter Sample Example");
        textWriter.WriteComment("myXmlFile.xml in root dir");

        textWriter.WriteStartElement("Student");
        textWriter.WriteStartElement("r", "RECORD", "urn:record");

        textWriter.WriteStartElement("Vorname", "");
        textWriter.WriteString(user1.Vorname);
        textWriter.WriteEndElement();

        textWriter.WriteStartElement("Nachname", "");
        textWriter.WriteString(user1.Nachname);
        textWriter.WriteEndElement();

        textWriter.WriteStartElement("Geburtstag", "");
        textWriter.WriteString(user1.Geburtstag.ToString());
        textWriter.WriteEndElement();

        textWriter.WriteStartElement("Alter", "");
        textWriter.WriteString(user1.Alter(user1.Geburtstag).ToString());
        textWriter.WriteEndElement();

        textWriter.WriteEndDocument();
        textWriter.Close();
    }
}

The ReadXML class:
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

    internal class ReadXML
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        Console.WriteLine(10);

        XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader("C:\\Users\\ematric\\Desktop\\Philipp\\Solution/myXmlFile.xml");
            textReader.Read();

            while (textReader.Read())
            {
                textReader.MoveToElement();
                Console.WriteLine("XmlTextReader Properties Test");
                Console.WriteLine("===================");

                Console.WriteLine("Name:" + textReader.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("Base URI:" + textReader.BaseURI);
                Console.WriteLine("Local Name:" + textReader.LocalName);
                Console.WriteLine("Attribute Count:" + textReader.AttributeCount.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Depth:" + textReader.Depth.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Line Number:" + textReader.LineNumber.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Node Type:" + textReader.NodeType.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Attribute Count:" + textReader.Value.ToString());

            }
        }

    }


The User class:
using System.Net.Mail;

internal class User
{
    public string Vorname;
    public string Nachname;
    public DateTime Geburtstag = new DateTime();
    private int alter;

        public int Alter(DateTime Geburtstag)
        {
            this.Geburtstag = Geburtstag;
            alter = (int) (DateTime.Now - Geburtstag).TotalDays / 365;
            return alter;
        }
}

When I launched the program in Visual Studio I got an error because the program didn´t know where to start, so i adjusted that the WriteXML class is executed firstly. The file was created as I had expected, but the ReadXML class didn´t read it. If the file is already created and I launch the ReadXML class at first, the file is read as I want it to.
So I´m wondering why the ReadXML class isn´t executed when the WriteXML is launched directly before it.

The Main Function is the entry point of your Application. In a project, there can ever only be one of those. That's why you needed to explicitly pick one. Which also means the other one will be ignored. How would any tool know in which order to execute a multitude of them. And sequentially? Or Concurrently?

the ReadXML class didn´t read it you didn't post any code that actually uses that class from WriteXML.Main so nothing will be executed.

What you can do, though is pass a cli argument to have your app execute one of those tasks (not in the System.Threading.Tasks.Task sense) for you. Like "mysuperduperapp writexml" and "mysuperduperapp readxml". Then you can evaluate that argument in your (single) Main method and execute functionality conditionally.

Or you separate the two functionalities into different projects. Then each project can have its own Main.

Unrelated: do not persist age in a property or field. You can and should always compute it from date-of-birth. (Sometimes it might be ok to cache it, though)

Also: There is XML-Serialization that will do all that WriteXXX for you. Is there a reason to do it manually?

all should be working.
also, you dont need to repeat same data in loop
still questioning why not use serialization - is there any specifics?
void Main()
{
    string xmlFile = "C:\\1\\myXmlFile.xml";
    if (!File.Exists(xmlFile))
        CreateXML(xmlFile);
    ReadXML(xmlFile);

}

internal void CreateXML(string xmlFile)
{
    User user1 = new User();
    user1.Vorname = "Max";
    user1.Nachname = "Mustermann";
    user1.Geburtstag = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1);
    user1.Alter(user1.Geburtstag);

    XmlTextWriter textWriter = new XmlTextWriter(xmlFile, null);
    textWriter.WriteStartDocument();

    textWriter.WriteComment("First Comment XmlTextWriter Sample Example");
    textWriter.WriteComment("myXmlFile.xml in root dir");

    textWriter.WriteStartElement("Student");
    textWriter.WriteStartElement("r", "RECORD", "urn:record");

    textWriter.WriteStartElement("Vorname", "");
    textWriter.WriteString(user1.Vorname);
    textWriter.WriteEndElement();

    textWriter.WriteStartElement("Nachname", "");
    textWriter.WriteString(user1.Nachname);
    textWriter.WriteEndElement();

    textWriter.WriteStartElement("Geburtstag", "");
    textWriter.WriteString(user1.Geburtstag.ToString());
    textWriter.WriteEndElement();

    textWriter.WriteStartElement("Alter", "");
    textWriter.WriteString(user1.Alter(user1.Geburtstag).ToString());
    textWriter.WriteEndElement();

    textWriter.WriteEndDocument();
    textWriter.Close();
}
internal void ReadXML(string xmlFile)
{
    XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader(xmlFile);
    textReader.Read();
    Console.WriteLine("XmlTextReader Properties Test");
    Console.WriteLine("Base URI:" + textReader.BaseURI);
    Console.WriteLine("===================");

    while (textReader.Read())
    {
        if (textReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("---");
            Console.WriteLine($"Attribute Count: {textReader.AttributeCount.ToString()}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Line Number: {textReader.LineNumber.ToString()}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Depth:{textReader.Depth.ToString()}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Name: {textReader.Name}: {textReader.ReadString()}");
        }
    }
}
internal class User
{
    public string Vorname;
    public string Nachname;
    public DateTime Geburtstag = new DateTime();
    private int alter;

    public int Alter(DateTime Geburtstag)
    {
        this.Geburtstag = Geburtstag;
        alter = (int)(DateTime.Now - Geburtstag).TotalDays / 365;
        return alter;
    }
}

xml file :
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--First Comment XmlTextWriter Sample Example-->
<!--myXmlFile.xml in root dir-->
<Student>
    <r:RECORD xmlns:r="urn:record">
        <Vorname>Max</Vorname>
        <Nachname>Mustermann</Nachname>
        <Geburtstag>1/1/2000 12:00:00 AM</Geburtstag>
        <Alter>24</Alter>
    </r:RECORD>
</Student>

result would be
XmlTextReader Properties Test
Base URI:file:///C:/1/myXmlFile.xml
===================
---
Attribute Count: 0
Line Number: 4
Depth:0
Name: Student:
    
---
Attribute Count: 0
Line Number: 6
Depth:2
Name: Vorname: Max
---
Attribute Count: 0
Line Number: 7
Depth:2
Name: Nachname: Mustermann
---
Attribute Count: 0
Line Number: 8
Depth:2
Name: Geburtstag: 1/1/2000 12:00:00 AM
---
Attribute Count: 0
Line Number: 9
Depth:2
Name: Alter: 24

